# Tkinter closing the gap between widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

i am sorry if  it looks messy but how do i shorten the gap between the entry widget and the label widget called "tag"  This is what it looks like right now:

[image: screenshot of current display]

I want the entry box and the word "grade" to stick together.I feel like there is a base distance between the grids so i tried some geometry features but couldn't figure it out

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *


win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("300x250")
win.title("Gpa Calculator")

def gpa_calc():
    pass

grade1 = tk.DoubleVar()
grade2 = tk.DoubleVar()
grade3 = tk.DoubleVar()
grade4 = tk.DoubleVar()
grade5 = tk.DoubleVar()
grade6 = tk.DoubleVar()


label1 = ttk.Label(win, text="Gpa Calculator",font = ("Times New Roman", 15)).grid(column=1,row=0,pady=0)



label1 = ttk.Label(win, text="Class 1").grid(column=0, row=1,)# Column ve row da degismesi gerekebilir
class1 = ttk.Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=grade1)
class1.grid(column=2, row=1,pady=5)
tag1 = ttk.Label(win, text="Gpa:").grid(column=1, row=1,)

label2 = ttk.Label(win, text="Class 2").grid(column=0, row=2,)
class2 = ttk.Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=grade2)
class2.grid(column=2, row=2,pady=5)
tag2 = ttk.Label(win, text="Gpa:").grid(column=1, row=2,)

label3 = ttk.Label(win, text="Class 3").grid(column=0, row=3,)
class3 = ttk.Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=grade3)
class3.grid(column=2, row=3,pady=5)
tag3 = ttk.Label(win, text="Gpa:").grid(column=1, row=3,)

label4 = ttk.Label(win, text="Class 4").grid(column=0, row=4,)
class4 = ttk.Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=grade4)
class4.grid(column=2, row=4,pady=5)
tag4 = ttk.Label(win, text="Gpa:").grid(column=1, row=4,)

label5 = ttk.Label(win, text="Class 5").grid(column=0, row=5,)
class5 = ttk.Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=grade5)
class5.grid(column=2, row=5,pady=5)
tag5 = ttk.Label(win, text="Gpa:").grid(column=1, row=5,)

label6 = ttk.Label(win, text="Class 6").grid(column=0, row=6,)
class6 = ttk.Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=grade6)
class6.grid(column=2, row=6,pady=5)
tag6 = ttk.Label(win, text="Gpa:").grid(column=1, row=6,)
```

Comment: Add `sticky="e"` to `grid(...)` on all *"tag"*.

Comment: Off-topic: The value being assigned to `label1`, `label2`, etc is `None` because that's the effective return value of all calls to the `grid()` method. The same thing is true of your `tag1`, `tag2`, etc variables for the same reason. It's not causing a problem in code in your question because you never reference them again, but generally it's something to avoid especially if you do need to refer to the widget again in the code.

Comment: @martineau You got different result because your code does not have `label1` with text "Gpa Calculator" at row 0 column 1.  The gap in OP result is mainly caused by this label.

Comment: @acw1668: Quite true…thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: @martineau Hello, according to what you've mentioned, i am working on another project right now and i think i am having the problem that you've mentioned.What is the way to reference labels again in the code that have used the grid() method ?

Comment: Berke: It's pretty simple - just split the operation up into two steps. Have the first step be creating the widget and assigning it to a variable, then on the next line use that variable to call its `grid()` method.

Comment: @martineau Thank you Very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top label is defining the width of the center column. One way to solve this is to give that top label all 3 columns:

```
label1 = ttk.Label(win, text="Gpa Calculator",font = ("Times New Roman", 15))
label1.grid(column=0,row=0,pady=0,columnspan=3)
```

Another good way to solve this is to make a dedicated Frame for the table, so that the Frame has it's own grid. Then you can put that Frame in another grid as a single object.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a pro, but can you delete paddings and use
win.columnconfigure and win.rowconfigure to set cell by cell (or a list of cells) settings of the grid like this :

```
win.columnconfigure(col,weight=1)
```

: **weight** makes a column or row stretchable. (You can set pad, too )

Sorry for my english, I'm sadly french